# Expected Randomness does not occur in Tensorflow Layer

Tags: tensorflow2.x

I wrote a custom layer that shuffle the input.  When I try to test the layer, said shuffling does not occur.  Here is my minimal noise layer below:

```
class ShuffleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ShuffleLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if training:
            shuffled = tf.stop_gradient(tf.random.shuffle(inputs))
            return shuffled
        return inputs
```

When I test the layer, the layer will not shuffle

```
SL = ShuffleLayer()
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(0,10, dtype=tf.float32), (5,2))
y = SL(x)
print(x.numpy())
print(y.numpy())
```

> [[0. 1.] [2. 3.] [4. 5.] [6. 7.] [8. 9.]]

> [[0. 1.] [2. 3.] [4. 5.] [6. 7.][8. 9.]]

Why will the expected behavior not occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the layer `call`, we see that the layer does nothing if `training` is `None`.  When the layer is called as `y = SL(x)`, it sees that `training` is `None` and returns the inputs.  Getting the shuffled output is done by turning on the training parameter:

```
y = SL(x, training=True)
print(x.numpy())
print(y.numpy())
```

> [[0. 1.][2. 3.][4. 5.][6. 7.][8. 9.]]

> [[0. 1.][6. 7.][2. 3.][8. 9.][4. 5.]]